# Is it possible to implement polymorphic functions in a DSL using Free

Tags: haskell, dsl, free-monad

I am building a small DSL using Free Monads.

I would like to be able to have polymorphic functions in my DSL.

An example of something I would like to build is this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Monad.Free.Church

data Queue a = Queue a

data MyDsl next =
  NewQueue (Queue a -> next) |
  WriteToQueue (Queue a) a next

makeFree ''MyDsl

testProgram :: F MyDsl
testProgram = do
  (intQueue :: Queue Int) <- newQueue
  (charQueue :: Queue Char) <- newQueue
  writeToQueue intQueue 1
  writeToQueue charQueue 'c'
```

The way I have encoded it above I get `Not in scope: type variable ‘a’`
errors which makes sense. Is there a way to have polymorphic functions in a DSL using Free?

For background the reason I would like to do this is so I can have a production interpreter that uses TQueue behind the scenes and a test interpreter that uses an in memory data structure for testing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can represent your DSL with a GADT

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Queue a = Queue a

data MyDsl next where
  NewQueue :: (Queue a -> next) -> MyDsl next
  WriteToQueue :: (Queue a) -> a -> next -> MyDsl next

deriving instance Functor MyDsl
```

Neither `makeFree` nor [`makeFreeCon`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free/docs/Control-Monad-Free-TH.html#v:makeFreeCon) can generate free polymorphic monadic actions for `MyDsl`. You will need to write them yourself.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Free.Class

newQueue :: (MonadFree MyDsl m) => m (Queue a)
newQueue = wrap $ NewQueue return

writeToQueue :: (MonadFree MyDsl m) => Queue a -> a -> m ()
writeToQueue q v = liftF $ WriteToQueue q v ()
```

Now you can write your test program.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Free.Church

-- testProgram can have a more general type
-- testProgram :: (MonadFree MyDsl m) => m ()
testProgram :: F MyDsl ()
testProgram = do
  (intQueue :: Queue Int) <- newQueue
  (charQueue :: Queue Char) <- newQueue
  writeToQueue intQueue 1
  writeToQueue charQueue 'c'
```

---

You may find your DSL is easier to write multiple interpreters for if you parameterize the type of a queue. If you do, you'll need a type family or functional dependency to determine the type of the queue from the type of the monad.

```
data MyDsl q next where
  NewQueue :: (q a -> next) -> MyDsl next
  WriteToQueue :: (q a) -> a -> next -> MyDsl next
```

Comment: Thank you Cirdec that is exactly what I was looking for. Nice tip about parameterising the queue type.